# Running a windows reg add command in non-interactive mode

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, non-interactive

I'm trying to write a small batch script that is supposed to change some registry entries.

Now to do that from the command line one would use the `reg add` command. And when the specified registry key already exists it asks to overwrite the value.

For example `reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Colors" /v Background /t REG_SZ /d "120 0 0"` yields `Value Background exists, overwrite(Yes/No)?` and only if I press `y` the command completes.

It does the same when the command is issued from a batch script. Since I would like the process to be automated and no further user input to be required I would like to remove the confirmation request. So is it possible to run this command non-interactively?

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `Reg Add /?` and press the enter key. The output clearly shows `/F` with the description, `Force overwriting the existing registry entry without prompt`. Given that, I'd suggest you change your command to `@"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Colors" /V Background /D "120 0 0" /F > NUL`. _(The `> NUL` is to hide any 'successful' messages being printed to the console)_.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the /F flag as mentioned by Compo in the comments, or you can use a `.reg` file and start it in silent mode:

```
start regedit /s "C:\path\to\regfile.reg"
```